# SQLite insert from Java ArrayList: Need to insert multiple rows

Tags: java, sqlite, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to insert rows into my SQLite DB from an ArrayList using a for loop, but I'm only getting one row in the DB rather than the multiple I expect.

See code segment below. Why is my code only inserting one row?

```
public class DbConnection {

    private static Connection conn;

    public static Connection Connector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:myDB.sqlite");
            return conn;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
    }
}



 public class Upload {

    public boolean setUpload(String eID, String rID, String cID, int res, int point) throws SQLException{
    connection = DbConnection.Connector();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement =null;
    String query = "Insert into Result (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        try {  
              preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);   
              preparedStatement.setString(1, eID);
              preparedStatement.setString(2, rID);
              preparedStatement.setString(3, cID);
              preparedStatement.setInt(4, res);
              preparedStatement.setInt(5, point);
              preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
              connection.commit();

        return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
        } finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
     }
  }


    //note ArrayList: "getList()" is sitting in another class.

    public void update() throws SQLException {
        for (int i=0; i<select.getSetUp().getList().size(); i++){
            setUpload(select.getSetUp().getEID(),
            select.getSetUp().getR().getId(), 
            select.getSetUp().getList().get(i).getId(),
            select.getSetUp().getList().get(i).getRes(),
            select.getSetUp().getList().get(i).getPoint());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The loop seems OK. `catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
        }` is not a good practice. Perhaps an exception happens in the loop? try adding `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch`

Comment: +1 for Yossi, also if u can pass the list itself to the `setUpload()` you can make that loop to iterate over (ps.set ... , and executeUpdate.execute...) this way you will use 1 connection... just a suggestion

Comment: Thanks Yossi. You are absolutely right. Like an idiot I forgot that I made eID a primary key. Primary key constraint seems to be the issue. I'll try to re-run now.

Comment: Thanks Yazan, yes that does seem more sensible

Comment: It's working now. Classic me: always something stupid.

Comment: Classic me: always something stupid :p u r so good in sarcasm. +1 for u :D